# Entity framework and Expression<Func<>> predicates on virtual properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to filter on a virtual (foreign keyed object) property of a EF entity with a Expression> predicate.

The predicate:

```
Expression<Func<AspNetUsers, bool>> HasKyc() {
    return user => (
        (user.IsProfessional && KycCorporations.Any(e => e.UserId.Equals(user.Id) && e.GovId.Equals(user.EntityGovId)))
        ||
        (!user.IsProfessional && KycIndividuals.Any(e => e.UserId.Equals(user.Id) && e.GovId.Equals(user.GovId)))
    );
}
```

If I use it like this:

```
AspNetUsers.Where(HasKyc())
```

It works fine, but then trying to apply to virtual properties:

```
Commitments.Where(e => !AspNetUsers.Where(f => f.Id.Equals(e.UserId)).Any(HasKyc()))
```

I get "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Any'".

Comment: What's `AspNetUsers`?

Comment: The name of the table that holds my users.

Comment: Shouldn't the Expression type be using `AspNetUser` rather than `AspNetUsers`?

Comment: My code is from LinqPad where the naming is a bit different.

Comment: @NielsBosma: try to cache `HasKyc` result in a local variable, e.g.: `var hasKyc = HasKyc(); Commitments.Where(e => !AspNetUsers.Where(f => f.Id.Equals(e.UserId)).Any(hasKyc));`.

Comment: I assume `AsetNetUsers` is a `DbSet` property of the context?

Comment: Also, why calling both `Where()` and `Any()` when the predicate can be expressed in a single `Any()`?

Comment: it looks strange, try hovering your mouse over `Where` (in `AspNetUsers.Where(`) to see if is actually an `IQueryable`. Again it appears very strange. There should be something wrong on your side that is not aware by others reading this question.

Comment: @Dennis Actually when testing in EF (LinqPad was running linq2sql in my test) your solution works! Thanks!